# How to show the shutdown and restart buttons in the KDE Plasma Application Menu widget

Tags: kde, plasma5

I'm using KDE Neon 5.24.  I'm using the Application Menu widget as my app launcher instead of the default Application Launcher widget.  When I first installed it, the Application Menu widget showed the shutdown and restart buttons in the left-side panel, along with the logout button.  After I updated the software today, the shutdown and restart buttons are no longer visible in the left-side panel, as seen in the screenshot below.  Is there any way I can get them back?  I know I can select the “Shut Down” option from the “Power / Session” sub-menu, but I like the convenience of having the buttons right there on the main panel.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Was about to "me too" this question, when I discovered the answer:

Open the **Power/Session** menu right at the bottom of the menu (*as shown in the original question*) and you will find your missing buttons.

**Right-click** on any one of them and **add to favorites** to show them in the favorites part of the menu.

Comment: They're also visible by default upon addition of the menu in `cpe:/a:kde:plasma:6.0.1`.